# from quickly.widgets import url_fetch_progressbar can not be found?

Tags: application-development, python, quickly

at the moment im creating a web browser using a mix of python and quickly(glade)

im trying to get the progress bar at the bottom of the page to work properly (with no luck atm)

i have inserted this bit of code :

```
from quickly.widgets import url_fetch_progressbar
```

to my main area (dmwebbrowserWindow.py)

when i run the package through command promt (quickly run)

i get an error message like this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/dm-web-browser", line 32, in <module>
    import dm_web_browser
  File "/home/matty/dm-web-browser/dm_web_browser/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from dm_web_browser import DmWebBrowserWindow
  File "/home/matty/dm-web-browser/dm_web_browser/DmWebBrowserWindow.py", line 19, in <module>
    from quickly.widgets import url_fetch_progressbar
ImportError: No module named widgets
```

any ideas how i fix this? (before i decide to give in and throw the laptop out the window)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install the package `python-quickly.widgets`

Either through the Software Center, Synaptic or the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python-quickly.widgets
```